# GCM Re-registration each time the App starts

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

After a full and clear registration on GCM, I have started my app. Also saved the Reg_Id in both local and server database. The app beautifully worked with the GCM Reg_Id for one or two days..Then STOP. First I thought there is some problem in my program, but at last I know the GCM Reg_Id for the current device is expired/useless.

After facing this issue several times, I decided to register the GCM each time the App starts. 
So in the `onCreate()` method of my `MainActivity` I did this:

```
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    if(!GcmResistered){
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
        GcmResistered = true;
    }

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    if(regId == null){
        GcmResistered= false;
    }       
    else{
      //Save it in local and server
    }
```

I followed the clumsy way. First I registered the GCM and then check it by `GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId()` method, only to avoid the Reg_Id expiring problem. Otherwise it just get the expired Reg_Id and skip the registration.

Is there any perfect way which help me to get rid from this clumsy approach.  I am fully hopeless on GCM_Reg ID only for this sudden dead.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem instead of re registration when app start you should write a `service` that should run in background in a day.

By doing this method you will have always updated GCM ID on your server and can be helpful according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to start a background service for this, coz it will take more resource than now. I just want to get rid from this re-registration.

Comment: @RanjitPati Don't keep it running always. Start it then do your work then stop it.

Comment: Alarm Task is also an option schedule it for once for a day.